# Why functions metaboxes is causing White Screen in Admin

Tags: functions, theme-development, hooks, child-theme, fatal-error

I am having an issue after migrating a project to other server. When I go to /wp-admin I am getting a 'White Screen of Death'. If I access to /wp-login.php instead I get the login form but with an advice

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You
>   must enable cookies to use WordPress.

Obviusly my browsers are okey, and I tried from other computers

I wasted hours looking for bug and finally I commented these lines...

```
<?php 
function portfolio_custombox($post) {
    $stored_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pageid_destino', true);
    ?>
    <div class="settBlock"><label for="page_color_scheme">  
    <input type="number" class="" value="<?php echo $stored_id ?>" for="pageid_destino" name="pageid_destino"><br>
    <label for="pageid_destino"><?php _e('Id de la página destino (este número es el que se presenta después del argumento ?post=<b>number</b>)', MY_THEME); ?></label>
<?php } ?>

<?php 
function portfolio_addmetaboxes() {
        $postypes = array('hgr_portfolio');
        foreach ( $postypes as $posttype ) {
            add_meta_box(
            'pageid_destino',
                __( 'ID de Página Destino', MY_THEME ),
                'portfolio_custombox',
                $posttype,
                'normal',
                'high'
            );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'portfolio_addmetaboxes' );
    function portfolio_savemetabox($post_id)
    {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['pageid_destino'] ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        $pageid_destino = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pageid_destino']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'pageid_destino', $pageid_destino );
    }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'portfolio_savemetabox' );
```

After commenting these lines my loggin is working back... but... why?

And why this is not happening in my local enviroment and previous host

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

After set WP_DEBUG to true I get this error...

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/my/staging/1/wp-content/themes/attractor-child/functions_includes/functions.metaboxes.php:12)
>   in
>   /home/my/staging/1/wp-content/themes/attractor/highgrade/framework/core/newsflash.php
>   on line 72

**UPDATE 2**

After I comment this line `/home/my/staging/1/wp-content/themes/attractor/highgrade/framework/core/newsflash.php` 
I get white screen without errors still with WP_DEBUG setted true...

Comment: Have you enabled `WP_DEBUG`?

Comment: Enable debug mode - the white screen of death will then change to a white screen with an error telling you what's wrong :)

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/my/staging/1/wp-content/themes/attractor-child/functions_includes/functions.metaboxes.php:12) in /home/my/staging/1/wp-content/themes/attractor/highgrade/framework/core/newsflash.php on line 72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution in codex....

> Interpreting the Error Message:
>
> If the error message states: Warning: Cannot modify header information
>   - headers already sent by (output started at /path/blog/wp-config.php:34) in /path/blog/wp-login.php on line 42,
>   then the problem is at line #34 of wp-config.php, not line #42 of
>   wp-login.php. In this scenario, line #42 of wp-login.php is the
>   victim. It is being affected by the excess whitespace at line #34 of
>   wp-config.php.
>
> If the error message states: Warning: Cannot modify header information
>   - headers already sent by (output started at /path/wp-admin/admin-header.php:8) in /path/wp-admin/post.php on line
>   569, then the problem is at line #8 of admin-header.php, not line #569
>   of post.php. In this scenario, line #569 of post.php is the victim. It
>   is being affected by the excess whitespace at line #8 of
>   admin-header.php.
>
> Other issues that might cause that error:
>
> In case you've used the function: wp_redirect() or tried to use a
>   header redirect after the header (or any content at all was sent) that
>   error message will pop. Instead use javascript redirection if needed.

I removed some extra spaces and everything is working back

```
add_meta_box(
            'pageid_destino',
                __( 'ID de Página Destino', MY_THEME ),
                'portfolio_custombox',
                $posttype,
                'normal',
                'high'
            ); //spaces were here
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer or this question will keep popping up as unsolved in the future.

Comment: I cant in 2 days... sry

Comment: sorry, forgot about that